# Control characters escaping in Erlang

Tags: erlang, control-characters

What is the right way to escape control characters in Erlang?

I do:

```
[EscapedString] = io_lib:format("~p", [Str]).
```

It works as I expect for `\t` and `\n` characters:

```
io_lib:format("~p", ["str\ning"]).

["\"str\\ning\""]
```

But for `\a` :

```
io_lib:format("~p", ["str\aing"]).

["\"straing\""]
```

and

```
io_lib:format("~p", ["a\x07"]).

[[91,["97",44,"7"],93]]
```

I need to get `"\"str\\aing\""` string and in file it should look like `"str\aing"`.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: In corresponding to [documentation](http://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/data_types.html#id72152)  this sequence doesn't escaping so if you need another behaviour just write own transforming function.

Comment: You probably want to use `~n` instead of `\n`--because erlang will convert `~n` to the proper newline sequence for the OS the program is running on.  Unlike in other languages, erlang does not do any newline conversions for `\n`.

Answer (score 3):

'a' is not a control character, so "\a" yields the same string as "a". If you really want a backslash in the result, you need to escape the backslash itself: `"str\\aing"`.

Use `lists:flatten(io_lib:format(...))` if you want the result to always be a flat string rather than a nested io-list, as in your last example.